# Wordpress Electro theme error on every page when running on xamp "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\electroraw\wp-content\themes\electro\inc\structure\layout.php on line 113
[Code Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd2rX.jpg)

Comment: check `isset($array['some_key'])` before using it.

Comment: Add your code here, don't add images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors